# Почему в Fiddler не показывается POSTDATA?

Tags: c#, fiddler

Вообщем, я делаю программу ( чекер ), которая проверяет верность данных от аккаунта ( логин и пароль ).
Я, со временем, столкнулся с POST-запросами, скачал программу Fiddler и начал их отслеживать.
Но тут есть одна делема: они практически не показываются.
Например, приведу один кусок кода, взятый с интернета:

```
POST http://www.----------.com/login/login HTTP/1.1
Host: www.----------.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 109
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Origin: http://www.----------.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.57 Safari/536.11
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: http://www.----------.com/login/login
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: xf_session=0c4e132b44ce81bdf93e70c57fe17eb6; __cfduid=d43498195638b2afe52ebaa9e1f97b8b31342586809; __cfduid=d43498195638b2afe52ebaa9e1f97b8b31342586809

login=USERNAME&register=0&password=PASSWORD&remember=1&cookie_check=1&redirect=forum%2F&_xfToken=
```

Соответственно, последняя строка позволяет понять, что надо отправлять на сервер `код`login=USERNAME&register=0&password=PASSWORD&remember=1&cookie_check=1&redirect=forum%2F&_xfToken= `.
У меня эта строка отсутствует вообще, даже среди тех немногих POST-запросов, которые до меня доходят.

Comment: Я вот не понял, фиддлер вообще не видит искомый запрос ? или не видит только пост-данные этого запроса ? Если второе, то покажите скрин вкладки Inspectors ->TextView

Comment: @Pavel Popov Не видит пост-данные. GET показываются.

Comment: Если вообще не видит запросов, то проверьте отлов HTTPS трафика в настройках, а также сам браузер должен быть "чистым", без программ перенаправления трафика (VPN например).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ ВПН-а и прочих программ нету. А что по поводу отлова траффика в настройках, то имеете в виду в настройках Фидлера?

Comment: Тут я скорей про расширения в браузере говорю. Настройки, да фидлера (Tools - Options - HTTPS - Capture Https Connects и Decrypt Https Traffic, он попросит установить сертификат в систему, что тоже надо сделать)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ , Прошу прощение, может быть, этот вопрос вас насмешит, но у меня в настройках только это - https://imgur.com/tbCGvbu

Comment: @EvgeniyZ , можете скринами скинуть, куда переходить?

Comment: Ну тогда это ставьте что на скрине. У вас новомодный `Fiddler Everywhere`, а не `Fiddler 4`. Лично для меня он показался урезанным и неудобным)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ А, тогда я лучше скачаю Fiddler 4. По нём больше информации в интернете ( заметил это во время поиска; только не знал, что это за версия ). 
Она же на офф.сайте есть?

Comment: [Да](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrBSM.jpg)

Comment: Кстати, ребят, я уже нашел, как отслеживать это всё чудо в хроме, но всёравно спасибо вам! Хоть тут нашел нормальных людей, в отличии от англоязычного stackoverflow, где моему вопросу накидали сразу -11 репы, а в комментах писали "What??", хотя, как по-мне, я, со стороны грамматики и со стороны логики, лексики, всё очень даже хорошо написал.
Спасибо, что уделили время.